# Can I hide the active Magento Theme name from frontend of the website

Tags: magento

In wordpress there is an option to hide the fact that your site is run on WordPress by using plugin - Hide my WP. Similarly is there any option to hide the theme name from frontend so that users will not know that the website is designed using Magento

Answer (score 0):

Just change your admin login folder to something unique such as (insertsomething)_admin so if someone tries (yourwebsite)/admin it just redirects to the homepage.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If I go to my website and press F12 in the header the theme name is displayed so is there a way to hide that?

Comment: What browser and version of Magento are you using ?